# Count occurence in column datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatable to display some data and I want to count of how many "type" I have

```
Date                | View video    | Reach     | Total     | Type
------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-06-29 16:43:20 | 11 044        | 42 534    | 737       | video
2018-06-29 09:46:50 | 12 432        | 51 810    | 458       | image
2018-06-26 21:30:34 | 15 755        | 43 787    | 482       | video
2018-06-25 21:30:34 | 31 568        | 60 515    | 1 626     | video
2018-06-25 10:08:08 | 13 570        | 49 178    | 987       | image
2018-06-21 11:49:26 | 12 653        | 44 985    | 1 236     | video
2018-06-20 21:30:43 | 23 829        | 61 983    | 2 296     | video
2018-06-20 17:01:44 | 13 834        | 44 522    | 931       | image
2018-06-20 15:42:53 | 18 227        | 53 173    | 1 578     | video
2018-06-20 13:30:32 | 9 788         | 43 049    | 806       | video
2018-06-20 09:54:47 | 7 169         | 38 241    | 282       | image
2018-06-19 17:54:58 | 13 757        | 48 787    | 1 180     | video
```

**Question**: How to show number of videos and images ( in above example i have 8 videos and 4 images )

I try in my code something like :

```
    $('#table-post').DataTable({

    "iDisplayLength": 100,
    drawCallback: function () {

        var count = api.column( 4 ) 
            .data()
            .search('video').length;

        console.log('count  >> ' + count);
    }
})
```

But it return the number of all row

Comment: what is your data object?

Comment: @ParthShah my data object come from a mysql request which I display in html